# JSP package problems

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I had all my servlets and classes in the default package. I have created these and JSP's and its all working fine.

However i want to import some of the classes into the JSP's so i moved all the classes and servelts into a new package called Driver. I did not change any code anywhere, just moved it into a new package. The application compiles just fine.

Now i cant seem to access any of my classes or servlets, any ideas?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class Driver.viewTrip or a class it depends on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check whether the correct class files and package structure is reflected in your servlet-container (tomcat) - i.e. whether in `WEB-INF/classes` everything is correct.
- don't write business-logic in jsps. Ideally, you shouldn't need to import anything in your jsps. As explained by BalusC in the comments, this can be done in a few steps

  1. in your servlet call `request.setAttribute("attributeName", value)`;
  2. forward to the jsp - `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourView.jsp").forward()`
  3. in your `.jsp` use the value that was set in the attribute (instead of obtaining it with business logic in the jsp itself)
- use lowercase for package names

Comment: How do i check WEB-INF/classes ?

Comment: @Taylor go to your tomcat/webapps/webapp folder. How are you deploying your app?

Comment: It seemed to work fine now that i have refactored it with a lower case package name, thankyou!

Comment: @Taylor here on SO, if an answer has worked for you, you are invited to mark it as accepted (there is a tick below the vote counter)

Comment: +1 for no business logic in JSP. Taylor: let a servlet put data as request/session attribute, forward the request to a JSP and use taglibs/EL in JSP to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you defined the package at the top of all your java files.

For example "src/Driver/viewTrip.java" would like like the following:

```
package Driver;

public class viewTrip {
    // ...
}
```

Take a look at [Creating and Using Packages](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/packages.html). I also highly recommend you to read the "Java Code Conventions". Since I am a new user, therefore I am only allowed to post one hyperlink so the link to the code conventions is (http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html)